# Plotly: How to filter a dataframe of a long format with a custom button?

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to find a solution within Plotly/Dash where I can filter the incoming data for a plot with the selection of a custom button.

For example, consider the following data:

```
 x  |    y   | Special

.23     .55       N
.11     .89       Y
.45     .34       Y
.91     .21       N
```

How could I make an 'updatemenu' addition to my plots that displays only the data points where Special='Y' with one button selection or all of the points with another selection'?

What I have now:

```
my_figure.update_layout(
                updatemenus=[
                    dict(
                        buttons=list([
                            dict(
                                args=[<unknown> (filter function goes here?)],
                                label="Only Special Data",
                                method="restyle"
                            ),
                            dict(
                                args=[<unknown> (filter function goes here?)],
                                label="All Data",
                                method="restyle"
                            )
                        ]),
                    ),
                ]
            )
```

I'm new to the custom button feature of Plotly so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How did my suggestion work out for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a button for a dataframe subset of each unique element of `df['special]` with:

```
buttons = []
# button with one option for each 'special'
for s in df['special'].unique():
    buttons.append(dict(method='restyle',
                        label=s,
                        visible=True,
                        args=[{'y':[df[df['special']==s]['y'].values],
                               'x':[df[df['special']==s]['x'].values],
                               'type':'scatter'}, ],
                        )
                  )
```

#### Plot: Selected button option is `N`

The complete code snippet below will also include an option to select all elements after you've made another selection

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[0.12,0.11, 0.45, 0.91],
                   'y':[0.55, 0.89, 0.34, 0.91],
                   'special':['N', 'Y', 'Y', 'N']})
df

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=df['x'], y = df['y'], mode = 'markers'))
# fig.show()

buttons = []
# button with one option for each 'special'
for s in df['special'].unique():
    buttons.append(dict(method='restyle',
                        label=s,
                        visible=True,
                        args=[{'y':[df[df['special']==s]['y'].values],
                               'x':[df[df['special']==s]['x'].values],
                               'type':'scatter'}, ],
                        )
                  )

# add first option for all 'special'
buttons.insert(0, dict(method='restyle',
                 label='all',
                 visible=True,
                 args=[{'y':[df['y'].values],
                        'x':[df['x'].values],
                        'type':'scatter'}, ],))

# some adjustments to the updatemenus
updatemenu = []
your_menu = dict()
updatemenu.append(your_menu)

updatemenu[0]['buttons'] = buttons
updatemenu[0]['direction'] = 'down'
updatemenu[0]['showactive'] = True

# add dropdown menus to the figure
fig.update_layout(showlegend=False, updatemenus=updatemenu)
fig.show()
```